# Can this incomplete type be improved to work with this C++ concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, gcc9, gcc10

The following code [works](https://godbolt.org/z/YesjMPE6v) as designed with g++ 9.3.1 and the old concepts TS.  But I haven't gotten it to work with g++ 10.3.1 and the C++ core language version of concepts:

```cpp
#if __cpp_concepts < 201707
#  define CONCEPT concept bool
#else
#  define CONCEPT concept
#endif

template<class T>
CONCEPT AcceptsEvents = requires (T t) {
  t.OnEvent();
};

template <AcceptsEvents T>
struct Inner { };

struct Outer {
  void OnEvent();
  Inner<Outer> inner;
};

int main() {
  Outer out;
}
```

Here's my g++ 9.3.1 compilation with concepts TS:

```bash
$ g++ -std=c++2a -fconcepts concepts.cpp
```

It builds with no errors.

Here's my g++ 10.3.1 compilation with the C++ concepts core language feature:

```bash
$ g++ -std=c++2a -fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=2 concepts.cpp
```

This fails to compile with the following paraphrased error message:

```bash
note: constraints not satisfied
required for the satisfaction of 'AcceptsEvents<T>' [with T = Outer]
 in requirements with 'T t' [with T = Outer]
note: the required expression 't.OnEvent()' is invalid, because
error: 't' has incomplete type
```

I've read both the [concepts TS](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/constraints) and [core language concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) pages at cppreference.com in detail, and I've read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553869) in an effort to coax `class Outer` into a complete type.  Any suggestions for design improvements to get the 10.3.1 version working like the old 9.3.1 version was?

Comment: any reason why you want it to work with the old concepts TS?

Comment: @bolov No, I just had the code working in g++ 9.3.1 (which didn't yet support C++20 core language concepts), and my code stopped building when I upgraded to g++ 10.3.1 recently.

Comment: then it's a red herring. It's fine to mention it, but don't lead with it. I would make the question strictly about the standard concepts. Then if you want you can mention it used to work in the old concepts TS, but as I've said, I don't think it's that relevant. Imho

Comment: I think you can do it with a static_assert: `template<class T> struct Inner { static_assert(AcceptsEvents<T>); };` but I haven't checked

Comment: @Artyer, that gives me `error: static assertion failed` with the same eventual detailed explanation (`error: 't' has incomplete type`)

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the fact that this compiled on gcc 9.3 with the TS was a gcc bug, not something about the TS having different rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the event logic. Depending on your data structures this could make sense or not.

### Inheritance

```
struct Event
{
    void OnEvent();
};

struct Outer : Event {
  Inner<Event> inner;
};
```

### Composition

```
struct Event
{
    void OnEvent();
};

struct Outer {
  Event evt;
  Inner<Event> inner;
};
```

Comment: I moved away from inheritance intentionally towards concepts, because under extremely stressing data loads, the concepts approach proved faster (using old concepts TS and g++ 9.3.1).  I can't use your composition suggestion, because my OnEvent() method needs access to Outer's private data.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto OnEvent(auto& t)->decltype(t.OnEvent()){
  return t.OnEvent();
}

template<class T>
concept AcceptsEvents = requires (T t) {
  OnEvent(t);
};

template <AcceptsEvents T>
struct Inner { };

struct Outer;
void OnEvent(Outer&);

struct Outer {
  void OnEvent();
  Inner<Outer> inner;
};

void OnEvent(Outer&o){o.OnEvent();}
```

that should work.  Not tested, little practical experience with concepts, so it could be wrong; but seems right to my head-compiler.

I changed the concept from requireing a method to a function call.  Then added a trampoline template that calls the method.  So it checks both; and existing types (when complete) should work.

This lets us define a free function on an incomplete `Outer` object, so `Outer` passes the test.

Throw in some namespaces and we can even call the trampoline.